# Start xterm instance with different configurations

Tags: x11, configuration, xterm, x-resources

It's there a way to start instances of `xterm` using different configuration files. Ex: `xterm -load .Xresources-1`, `xterm -load .Xresources-1`

Using `xrdb -load ~/.Xdefaults` changes the configs globaly which I try to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's usually done by changing the *instance name*, which by default is the name of the program which is run, but can be overridden using the [`-name`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#X-Toolkit-Options:-name) option.  (If you make a symbolic link to a program and run that link, that's a quick way of renaming a program as well).

If you have a resource file with settings like

```
xterm*font: fixed
```

the **instance** is the `xterm` at the beginning of the line.

You can also change the *class name* (which you commonly see as `XTerm`, also at the beginning of the resource lines).  The [`uxterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#uxterm_man) script uses the [`-class`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-class) option to override this to change settings to make `xterm` work consistently in UTF-8 mode.

If you have different class names, then you can use the app-defaults search mechanism to support different resource files.  I set the environment variable `XAPPLRESDIR` to my own directory, and have locally-customized resource files (each named for a *class*).  That is documented in [X(7)](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html):

> *application-specific files*
>       Directories named by the environment variable **`XUSERFILESEARCHPATH`** or the environment variable **`XAPPLRESDIR`** (which names a single directory and should end with a **`'/'`** on POSIX systems), plus directories in a standard place (usually under **`/tmp/Xorg-KEM/lib/X11/`**, but this can be overridden with the **`XFILESEARCHPATH`** environment variable) are searched for for application-specific resources. For example, application default resources are usually kept in **`/tmp/Xorg-KEM/lib/X11/app-defaults/`**. See the *X Toolkit Intrinsics - C Language Interface* manual for details.

Comment: It'd be great if xterm would let command line options override anything in Xresources. That way we could run `xterm -fn fixed` and have it do the right thing even if Xresources has faceName defined.